# Erlang BinString Match

Tags: binary, erlang, match

I am new to Erlang, how to match the method 'getage' and 'getcity' from the url?

```
<<"http://server:port/getage?param=ABC">>
<<"http://server:port/getcity?param=ABC">>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard [`http_uri:parse/1` function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/http_uri.html#parse-1) for this, but note that it takes a list argument, not a binary, so we first convert your URL to a list via `binary_to_list/1`:

```
1> http_uri:parse(binary_to_list(<<"http://server:12345/getage?param=ABC">>)).
{ok,{http,[],"server",12345,"/getage","?param=ABC"}}
```

Assuming the function succeeds, it returns `{ok, {Scheme, UserInfo, Host, Port, Path, Query}}`. You can pattern-match that to extract the part you want, like this:

```
2> {ok, {_, _, _, _, "/"++Path, _}} = http_uri:parse(binary_to_list(<<"http://server:12345/getage?param=ABC">>)).
{ok,{http,[],"server",12345,"/getage","?param=ABC"}}
3> Path.
"getage"
```

The variable `Path` now contains what you want, but as a string, not a binary. You can just use `list_to_binary/1` to convert it back to a binary if you like:

```
4> list_to_binary(Path).
<<"getage">>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible way you could do it:

```
<<"http://server:port/", Uri/binary>> = <<"http://server:port/getage?param=ABC">>,
[Endpoint, _] = binary:split(Uri, <<"?">>),
io:format("~s~n", [Endpoint]).

%= getage
```

The reason why it's not possible to do it solely using pattern matching is that the `Endpoint` could be of any length and binary pattern matching requires that all binary fields have a size except for the last one. That's why running the following code won't work.

```
<<"http://server:port/", Uri/binary, "?", _/binary>> = <<"http://server:port/getage?param=ABC">>.

%% * 1: a binary field without size is only allowed at the end of a binary pattern
```